# How to read variables from external file in python 3.x?

Tags: python, exec, global, local

I have the following file (X:\somepath\somefile):

```
# This is a file containing default values
# It contains variables that users can change
val_1 = 123
val_2 = 456
print(val_1)
```

How do i get these variables in to a python script that looks like this:

```
@session.defButton('button name') # 3rd party thing
def stuff():
    file_name = 'X:\\somepath\\somefile' 
    exec(open(file_name, 'r').read()) # I used to use execfile(file_name) in 2.4
    print(val_2)
```

It prints val_1 but not val_2. This is the error i get

```
NameError: global name 'val_2' is not defined
```

How do i get it defined outside of the exec() function or are there more correct ways to get variables from external files? I don't get in what format the globals/locals need to be in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly please check if val_1 gets printed due to the print(val_1) statement in some file since you run an exec on its content

Also you can try replacing backslashes with forward slash in the path (change \\ to /)

Comment: val_1 gets printed, but not val_2. I've tried \\ and /, still no change.

Comment: Can you clarify why print(val_1) is in the external file and print(val_2) is in the script? Try placing both in the script file and see what happens. If you get error on both lines it just means that the file is not being fetched or the fetched file does not have these variable assignments. You can also try printing out the file content to see if it is as expected using 'print open(filename, 'r').read()

Comment: Ohh...Sorry, I should have been more clear, the print was just to show the symptom of the problem I'm having with my real script.
The real problem being that variables don't exist outside of the exec call.

Comment: In that case the file is getting executed as val_1 is getting printed whose print command is in the file. That means val_2 is also available after that. Most probably you are getting val_2 before exec. Otherwise, this is just weird.

Comment: No, it's all in the right order. I'm leaning towards the weird-option, thinking it's the third party software executing the script that causes the problem, but many thanks for your help!

Comment: You are most welcome! These kind of tricky problems are the best things to learn a new language which I am doing now. Please do share the solution once you find it.